# Shortened filename on Windows with Syntology NAS

Tags: windows, filesystems, nas

Folders on Syntology NAS that contain an accent character are shown shortened on my Windows 7 machine.
i.e
Folder Béla Fleck and The Flecktones is shown in Windows as W:\Music\B39PEX~5

Why is this so, and can I change this so it doesnt happen

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken this is most certainly Samba server issue. Samba is file accessing, sharing and exchanging protocol. And in most times it doesn't like UTF-8 encoded file names. If you have some old version of Samba installed on your NAS, this could be the answer. Plus: if your NAS runs under Linux and you access it from Windows, an additional problems takes place, as any Windows' Samba client is so poorly written that is has many issues and problems, which you won't find in Samba clients for other systems.

In general, solution is only one: Stop using non-standard characters in your file names and folders. I wasted so many hours on finding similar solution and ended up with a big rename solution to get rid of such "bulky" names.